# How to less from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to reduce value tabel A - tabel B = tabel C

```
 TABEL A
ID  PRICE
11   720
12   220
13   370

 TABLE B
ID  PRICE
11   420
12   110
13   140
```

The output I want is

```
 TABEL C
ID  PRICE
11   300
12   110
13   230
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `-`.

Comment: What language do you want to use to achieve these results? SQL? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner join like below to do that:

```
Select A.ID, (A.PRICE - B.PRICE) as PRICE
from A
inner join B on B.ID = A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

in case table A always have larger value than table B

```
SELECT A.ID , (A.PRICE - B.PRICE) AS PRICE FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

if A doesn't always have larger value than B , you can use the function `ABS`

```
SELECT A.ID , ABS(A.PRICE - B.PRICE) AS PRICE FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```